# Azure Devops Pipeline build fails hudson.security.AccessDeniedException3: *** is missing the Job/Build permission

Tags: azure-pipelines-build-task

I am using Jenkins to run build which is integrated to Azure Devops.

My Azure Pipeline build fails with the error:

`Job creation failed.`

`HttpResponse.statusCode=500`

`HttpResponse.statusMessage=Server Error`

`hudson.security.AccessDeniedException3: *** is missing the Job/Build permission`

Where can I start looking to troubleshoot this error, please?

Regards and Thanks for the help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved. The issue was there was no permission from my jenkins build user. I just gave the build attribute permission to the user from within the Jenkins platform